How to expand all entities in an OData GET request in SAP SuccessFactors
I'm using the Postman app to make a GET request to an OData service. I have more than 100 entities in my OData model, and instead of specifying each one individually, I want to expand all of them in a single request.
I tried using the $expand=* query option, but it didn’t work for me.
got this error message:
Unable to understand API request with character sequence: * at character position number: 0 invalid characters: * .
Is there any other way to achieve this? I couldn’t find any alternative methods.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

What did you actually use? What API are you calling? Does the API you call allow $expand=* in the first place? OData and GraphQL only allow you to use options the developer has enabled, to prevent badly written clients from executing unoptimized queries and slowing down the system. Trying to load 100 related entities can be very heavy unless the API is written explicitly to allow this

It seems this is a duplicate of SAP OData Generator generates bad URL for navigated entries. What you posted isn't an OData error, it's specific to the service. Googling shows it's returned by SAP SuccessFactors, which doesn't allow *

Ohh yeah I'm using SAP SF, so I cant use * to expand all entities.
Is there any other way to do it?

No. SAP doesn't want you to retrieve all the relations at once. This isn't a matter of OData syntax.

Ok, thank you very much
